# Search filtering from database likr facebook **find friends** page, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, checkbox, filtering

[image: How to create a search filter like the find friends page on facebook]

How to create a search filter like the find friends page on facebook. I have 3 column **bodybuild, ethnictype, skincolor** in table **accounts**. I already created the view for my page and the checkboxes in it doesn't filtering the values now. It displays all the values that i checked without filtering. I just need , if bodybuild=1 AND ethnictype=2 AND skincolor=1, I want to display the name of the user which has this values in his row.

heres the code which i use now,

here is the new updated code,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
$pro_price = $_REQUEST['pro_price'];
$pro_code = $_REQUEST['pro_code'];
$hsn_code = $_REQUEST['hsn_code'];
foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_price'] as $pro_price) {
    $statearray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_price);
}
foreach ($_REQUEST['pro_code'] as $pro_code) {
    $codesarray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($pro_code);
}
foreach ($_REQUEST['hsn_code'] as $hsn_code) {
    $hsnarray[] = mysql_real_escape_string($hsn_code);
}
$states = implode ("','", $statearray);
$codes = implode ("','", $codesarray);
$hsn = implode ("','", $hsnarray);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM addproduct WHERE pro_price IN ('$states') OR pro_code IN ('$codes') OR hsn_code IN ('$hsn')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
}
else
{
    echo "<table border='1' width='900' class='srchrslt'>
    <tr class='head'>
    <td>pro_name</td>
    <td>pro_brand</td>
    <td>hsn_code</td>
    <td>pro_price</td>
    <td>pro_code</td>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))
    {              
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_name'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_brand'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['hsn_code'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_price'] . " </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pro_code'] . " </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}}
```

for example if I select pro_code as 101 and hsn_code as 101101 and pro_price as 250 ,I want to view the **View Sonic LCD** as to my database here,

[image]

I need to filter my data values like if the codition like i above said , if bodybuild=1 AND ethnictype=4 AND skincolor=6, I want to display the dateils of the user which is in that table. the values of column can be changed according to our selection on checkboxes

Comment: why are you using the `mysql_` library? It was deprecated years ago due to security issues and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written with this API. Instead use mysqli or PDO which offer better security and enable prepared statements to protect against SQL injection attacks. Whoever suggested you to use `mysql_*` needs to update their information urgently.

Comment: But aside from that, you haven't said what's wrong with the code you have now. What problem are you having? All we have got is your requirements, and some code, and no indication of what your question is.

Comment: i need to filter my data values like if the codition like i above said , if bodybuild=1 AND ethnictype=4 AND skincolor=6, I want to display the dateils of the user which is in that table. the values of column can be changed according to our selection on checkboxes

Comment: Yes...that's what you want to do. What problem are you having with achieving it? What's wrong with your code? Give us a clue :-). Just from looking at it, it does seem like the query in the code above (going to an "addproduct" table and filtering by pro_price) has nothing to do with the table or fields you mention in the question (accounts table with ethnicity etc). So I'm confused. Is this code your attempt at solving it? Or just some random code from somewhere else? Have you actually tried to do this at all? We don't give out whole solutions on this site, we fix bugs with existing code.

Comment: @ADyson I need to filter the data using the checkbox values, not to search each of them. I have updated my question with my database table. Please check it. This is the code which I currently use. I want to edit this code with condition as i said

Comment: In the question you said "I have 3 column bodybuild, ethnictype, skincolor in table accounts." This is completely unrelated to any of the data fields in your code or in your table screenshot.  That's why I don't understand your requirements. There's seemingly no link between your code/database and your stated requirements.

Comment: its just an example . i need to fetch an another table iam working on ftp acces now. please help. I just want to tell you what i need this is just for an example

Comment: Try and write the code to filter on the fields you actually talk about in the question, then ask a question if you get stuck on _that_. You need to throw this all away anyway and start again because of the DB library issue anyway. This example you've got is no good. And like I said, we don't give out whole solutions here. Show us _your_ code and we'll happily help you fix bugs in it. It's clear now that you haven't even started to do the work. Seems like you've just pulled a random example off the internet without understanding it, and hoped someone else will alter it for you.

Comment: sorry, i havent any updated db on my hand.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying, you need to go away and start the work, and then come back if you have a problem with _your_ code, not someone else's barely related, out-of-date example. This is not a free write-all-my-code service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last with the help of **AJAX** I got the solutions to my question. Thanks to all of them who had supported me. Iam posting the code for further candidates.

**index.php**

```
<body>
<h1>Demo</h1>
<table id="employees"><thead>
<tr><th>Name</th>
<th>BodyBuild</th>
<th>EthnicType</th>
<th>Skincolor</th></tr>
</thead><tbody></tbody>
</table>
<div id="filter">
<h2>Filter options</h2>
<div>
<h4>Body Build</h4>
<input type="checkbox" id="car" name="sixpack">
<label for="car">Six Pack</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="car" name="fat">
<label for="car">Fat</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="car" name="thin">
<label for="car">Thin</label>
</div>
<div>
<h4>Ethnic Type</h4>
<input type="checkbox" id="language" name="arab">
<label for="language">Arab</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="language" name="indian">
<label for="language">Indian</label>
</div>
<div>
<h4>Skin Color</h4>
<input type="checkbox" id="nights" name="black">
<label for="nights">Black</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="nights" name="white">
<label for="nights">White</label>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function makeTable(data){
var tbl_body = "";
$.each(data, function() {
var tbl_row = "";
$.each(this, function(k , v) {
tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
})
tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
})
return tbl_body;
}
function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){
var opts = [];
$checkboxes.each(function(){
if(this.checked){
opts.push(this.name);
}
});
return opts;
}
function updateEmployees(opts){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search",
dataType : 'json',
cache: false,
data: {filterOpts: opts},
success: function(records){
$('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
}
});
}
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
updateEmployees(opts);
});
updateEmployees();
</script>
</body>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=castingkall', 'root', '');
$select = 'SELECT name,bodybuild,ethnictype,skincolor';
$from = ' FROM accounts';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
if (in_array("sixpack", $opts)){
$where .= " AND bodybuild = 1";
}
if (in_array("fat", $opts)){
$where .= " AND bodybuild = 2";
}
if (in_array("thin", $opts)){
$where .= " AND bodybuild = 3";
}
if (in_array("arab", $opts)){
$where .= " AND ethnictype = 4";
}
if (in_array("indian", $opts)){
$where .= " AND ethnictype = 5";
}
if (in_array("black", $opts)){
$where .= " AND skincolor = 6";
}
if (in_array("white", $opts)){
$where .= " AND skincolor = 7";
}
$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Just change the database name, table name and column name according to your data.

Hope you find this useful...